# Where are WEKA installed packages stored

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I would like to use the WEKA library in a Java program but I can't seem to find the methods I installed using WEKA's package manager.

Does anyone know where the installed methods are stored?

For clarification, I installed WEKA, installed the extra package using WEKA and can use it with the WEKA GUI. But I can't find the installed package in the .lib file.

Comment: Fyi you only need to locate the file weka.jar which contains all the weka libraries

Comment: Thanks for the comment Erwan, not all packages are in the weka.jar. When you install a package using their package manager, they're stored in the packages folder, which I didn't know existed until now.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: That's why I posted the question, I couldn't find the method I wanted in the jar and didn't know packages were stored elsewhere. Hopefully others will see my answer and won't spend as much time looking as I did haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how WEKA stores the extra packages on other installations, but for my Windows 10 with WEKA 3.8 it was here:

WEKA stores the extra packages in a direcory called packages. This package was in my user directory and under the wekafiles folder.

Example: "C:\Users\myUser\wekafiles\packages....."

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the **regular installed Weka (x64) files** at

```
C:\Program Files\Weka-x-y-z
```

where x-y-z is the version number. If you want to find a **specific package**, open the **weka-src.jar** file using [**Winrar**](https://www.rarlab.com/) or [**Winzip**](https://www.winzip.com/landing/download-winzip-v1.html). Then you will be able to find all the regular packages inside the archive following the package structure.

For the packages you install using the **package manager** they are located at

```
%userprofile%\wekafiles\packages
```